# Web Api action is not invoked when body is present. But works without body

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

The action defined as

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/someinterestingroute/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult PostSome(int id, [FromBody] BodyModel model)
```

And the model

```
public class BodyModel
{

    [JsonProperty("field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Using Postman

```
Action
POST
----------------------------------------------------
url - localhost/myAppName/api/someinterestingroute/5
----------------------------------------------------
Headers
Content-Type: application/json
----------------------------------------------------
Body
{
  "field1": "xxx",
  "field2": "yyy"
}
```

**Behavior**

When body is present in postman, I don't hit the action `PostSome` and get `unsupported media type` error in response.

When body is empty, I hit `PostSome`, I see `id=5` and `model` is `null`.

A little detail is, the controller is actually `ODataController`. But I've added this as non-OData action

Thanks A Lot!

Comment: Pay attention to the 415 error code. It's telling you something important here. You misspelled the content type header value.

Comment: Cannot you pass the id as a property of the body object?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I wish it was THAT easy. I mistyped it here but in postman it is ok - I copied it. Thanks

Comment: @Koga I tried it. Same bad luck. Even worse

Comment: It's difficult to say what's going on then. Try applying `[Consumes("application/json")]` to the method.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Not available

Comment: Sorry, I misread the tag. You're using WebAPI 2 and I thought otherwise

Comment: Can you show screenshots of postman showing the request and response?

Comment: @IvanVargas What I have in the question is literally what I have, Response is `500 Internal Server Error` but in the code, where trace is written, I see `415 unsupported media type`. I mean, I have placed break points in code and this is how I can tell if the action hit or missed. I only added that I have POST

Comment: For what you describe everything looks fine, probably is something minor in the request data, hence the reason to ask for it.

Comment: @IvanVargas there was nothing wrong with the request. The secret here laid  in the last paragraph of this question.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After trying several different techniques I found a way to do it and a reason why it didn't work.

As question mentioned - `ODataController` was the culprit after all. Solution is to create new controller deriving from `ApiController` and prefixed with same route as original `ODataController` controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/someinterestingroute")]
```

And the action now looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult PostSome(int id, BodyModel model)
```

And now, I have all my pieces work in a fine manner. **Lesson learned** - do not mix non-OData actions into `ODataController`. Although, the problem was the body and not the route. Certainly, there is something in OData routing and binding that prevented expected data binding.

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention here:

```
Content-Type: appliocation/json
```

you wrote it wrong. The correct is application/json

Comment: Sorry. I wrote it wrong in the question but not in real code. I fixed the question. Thanks